# convert time series plot using matplot to plotly

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plotly

I recently come across plotly which is a very powerful interactive online plot system. So i was thinking converting plots generated by matplot into plotly. Everything works fine except for the time series plot.

here is a simple version of my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.tools as tls
tls.set_credentials_file(
        username="edwinwang1988", 
        api_key="o8xw6s61dn")
import numpy as np

x = pd.date_range('1/1/2001',periods =72,freq='D')  # genrate a date range
Series = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['Date']) # generate a date range data frame

np.random.seed(0)
col = ['A','B','C','D'] #set col names for return series
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(72,4),columns=col) # generate random return series with col names as col
for i in range(len(col)):
    s[col[i]] = s[col[i]].cumsum()

s['Date']=x  # add date to dataframe s
s.plot(x='Date') # plot s and set date as x axis
```

this works fine and give me the plot i want with date as x axis. but when i tried to convert the figure to plotly.

```
mpl_fig2= plt.gcf()
py.iplot_mpl(mpl_fig2,strip_styple = True,filename='test')
```

i am seeing code error like "min() arg is an empty sequence" and sometimes this "year=1 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900"

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, I work for Plotly.

**tl;dr:**

run this in your terminal and it should be fixed:

`pip install --upgrade plotly`

**Context:**

So, pandas can do some funny things to dates in matplotlib. This is how matplotlib handles dates, basically:

*day 1 of year 1 in utc is the floating point 1.0*

http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#module-matplotlib.dates

Depending on how you use pandas to format your dates, you can end up with a pandas TimeSeries_DateFormatter. To the best of my knowledge, the repercussion of this is actually to change the underlying data associated with the date times to the following convention:

*day 1 of year 1970 in utc is the floating point 0.0*

So, days (not seconds!) since the epoch (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Fyi, this goes back to ~`9-22-1677` by using negative numbers.

**Issue:**

plotly was treating datetimes inside matplotlib as matplotlib datetimes, but pandas adds a formatter that changes this. A patch is added in plotly 1.4.2

Comment: still doesn't work for some reason. I am getting the same error code.
@theengineear